# Tinymce text area resizing with dragging bottom status bar

Tags: jquery, wordpress, resize, tinymce

I am new to WordPress. Is there any way to resize TinyMCE text area by dragging the  bottom border line?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any way to add resize implementation in the bottom line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it with some css trick.

```
     $('.tox-statusbar').css('padding', '0');
     $('.tox-statusbar__text-container').addClass('statusbar-text-container');
     $('.tox-statusbar__wordcount').addClass('statusbar-wordcount');
     $('.tox-statusbar__branding').addClass('d-none');
     $('.tox-statusbar__resize-handle').addClass('statusbar-resize-handle');
```

and;

```
.statusbar-text-container {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.statusbar-wordcount {
    margin-right: 3% !important;
}

.statusbar-resize-handle {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    cursor: ns-resize !important;
}
```

This actually extends the default resize part of textarea  to the tinymce bottom bar.

Answer (score 1):

inspect the area with ctrl+shift+I and then the HTML code appear to inspect it and add the CSS in right side try it and then in Wordpress customization  there is additional CSS so you can add your custom CSS